# In python, how do we write a regex pattern that does a OR condition between variables

Tags: python

Here is the problem. In this case how do I match string containing either "foo" or "bar".

`a = 'foo'`

`b = 'bar'`

`string = 'The bar is closed'`

reg = re.match(a + r"|" + b + r"(.*)", string)

Comment: What's wrong with `foo|bar`?

Comment: These are variables whose value also is dynamic. It is not sure that I always get foo or bar. I might get something else as well

Comment: So you want `\b(?:foo|bar)\b`?

Comment: No. There will be two variables (whose value can be anything) and I need to check the regex has any of them matching. In perl it is something like $string =~ /($variable1|$variable2)/ . This is what I'm looking for

Comment: I don't understand. You want to use the regex *on* the variables? So something like `reg_a = re.match(some_regex, a)` and `reg_b = re.match(some_regex, b)`? Please try to clarify your question and add some example in- and output.

Comment: Are you asking how to do string interpolation/formatiing?

Comment: `a + r"|" + b + r"(.*)"` would work fine. However, use `re.search` instead of `re.match`, because `re.match` *always matches from the beginning. It would be like adding an `^` anchor...

Comment: Hi Juanapa, Thanks a lot it worked.. Actually I tried a similar thing before. But looks like I made a mistake in there.